# How to resolve 'error - InvalidDatasourceError: Datasource URL should use prisma'

Tags: next.js, prisma

So I am using Prisma as an ORM on my project to communicate with the database that I set up with AWS. Not happy with the AWS service I am now switching my database to `railway.app` - which is working out well for me. However, I set up a Prisma `data proxy` on my app with the AWS connection string, and now that I don't seem to want/ need it anymore I removed it but getting an error:

```
error - InvalidDatasourceError: Datasource URL should use Prisma:// protocol. 
If you are not using the Data Proxy, remove the data proxy from the preview features in your 
schema and ensure that PRISMA_CLIENT_ENGINE_TYPE environment variable is not set to data proxy.
```

Since getting the error I have removed `previewFeatures = ["dataProxy"]` from the `prisma.schema` file to make it look like this (back to what it was before configuring with dataproxy):

```
generator client {
      provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
      provider = "postgresql"
      url= env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

but the error still persists, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

running `prisma generate` fixes this issue